# Java Reference Variable Counting

Tags: java, object, reference

In this snip of code, there are 2 objects being created, but why are there only 4 reference variables created?

```
class Customer {
    public int custId;
    public String custName;
}

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Customer obj = new Customer();
        Customer objOne = new Customer();
        Customer objTwo;
        Customer objThree = obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think there should be more?

Comment: How many reference variables do you expect there be?

Comment: I thought there would be 6, 2 strings created by new objects, then the 4 customer variables in main

Comment: I see 6 variable declarations, 1 of *primitive* type and 5 of *reference* type. Fields are variables too. --- *FYI:* Reference variables aren't *created*, they are *declared*. Object *instances* are created. Double-check your terminology to make sure you actually asked what you intended to ask.

Comment: Your argument is valid in some definition of "variable". Who told you there are 4?

Comment: @Andreas - According to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3) regarding instance variables: "If a class T has a field `a` that is an instance variable, then a new instance variable `a` is created and initialized to a default value (§4.12.5) as part of each newly created object of class T or of any class that is a subclass of T." There is similar language regarding local variables and entering blocks or `for` statements. So in the terminology of the JLS, reference variables can indeed be created.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there are various *types* of variables, falling into two broad categories: primitive types and reference types. There are also eight *kinds* of variables (see [The Java Language Specification, §14.12.3,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3)). The relevant pieces of the spec regarding kinds of variables are:

> 2. An *instance variable* is a field declared within a class declaration without using the keyword `static` (§8.3.1.1).
>     If a class T has a field `a` that is an instance variable, then a new instance variable `a` is created and initialized to a default value (§4.12.5) as part of each newly created object of class T or of any class that is a subclass of T (§8.1.4)....

> 8. *Local variables* are declared by local variable declaration statements (§14.4).
>    Whenever the flow of control enters a block (§14.2) or `for` statement (§14.14), a new variable is created for each local variable declared in a local variable declaration statement immediately contained within that block or `for` statement.

In your code, I count the following reference variables:

- Four local variables in method `main()`: `obj`, `objOne`, `objTwo`, and `objThree`.
- In `main()`, two instances of `Customer` are created. Each instance creation brings into existence one additional instance variable of reference type for the `Customer` field `custName`. (Each new instance also brings into existence one instance variable of primitive type for the field `custId`.)

That is a total of six reference variables. Why do you think only 4 are created?

If you are drawing this conclusion by examining the generated byte code, it is possible that some of the local variables in `main()` were optimized away by the compiler, since (at least) two of the variables go out of scope immediately after they are created (and one is not even assigned a value).

Comment: A reference manual through my work claims there are only 4 reference variables created in this scenario, I thought there would be 6. Being very new to java I am not sure what the actual answer is

Comment: So then my thought process is "okay are the Strings in class not counting as reference variables or are obj and objOne in main not counting as reference variables"

Comment: @tHatpart - I would say that your reference manual is simply wrong. My guess is that the manual authors probably counted the two String fields, obj, and objOne (since they are initialized to new Customer objects) but failed to count objTwo and objThree (wrongly thinking that they were not counted as reference variables since they were either not initialized or initialized to an existing reference). But that's just a guess and you'd have to ask the manual authors what their thinking was.